# Where does ForerunnerDB save its Database?

Tags: javascript, html, database, web, forerunnerdb

I am about to write an HTML file which is supposed to run in the browser  locally, create and modify a database (Forerunner DB) , and show some results.

I wrote the below , where should I find the database file ?
is the below enough "once the page is loaded " to sse the DB or there is some "save" command ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>ouch</title>
<body>
<p id="out">Testing..</br> >
</body>
<script src="C:\Users\n17263\node_modules\forerunnerdb\js\dist\fdb-all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
var db = new ForerunnerDB('db');
var Customers= db.collection('Customers');
var Suppliers= db.collection('Suppliers');
var Items= db.collection('Items');
var S_ITMES= db.collection('S_ITEMS');
var Purchase_Invoices= db.collection('Purchase_Invoices');
var Sales_Invoices= db.collection('Sales_Invoices');
var Orders= db.collection('Orders');
Customers.insert({name:'Mohammad'});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It saves the database to [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API), WebSQL or [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). You can specify this manually, as the documentation shows [here](https://github.com/Irrelon/ForerunnerDB#manually-specifying-storage-engine).

Comment: it mentions that the standard engine is indexed DB . where shall I find the file of that DB ?

Comment: If you are using Node.js rather than a browser, ForerunnerDB will save to whatever folder you specify.

Comment: When you say whatever folder, do you mean a folder server-side or client-side ?